# What is a good way to emulate casting?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

From [underscoresjs.org](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js)

```
  // Generate a unique integer id (unique within the entire client session).
  // Useful for temporary DOM ids.
  var idCounter = 0;
  _.uniqueId = function(prefix) {
    var id = ++idCounter + '';
    return prefix ? prefix + id : id;
  };
```

It appears that this line:

```
var id = ++idCounter + '';
```

casts a number to a string by concatenating it with the empty string.

Is this a good way to cast from a number to a string?

Comment: Define 'good'. `+''` is shorter than both `.toString()` and `String()` constructs, and is actually a well-known JS idiom, so if your definition of 'good' include readability and compactness, this approach is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a good way to cast to a string.

If you want something more explicit, use `.toString()`.

```
var id = (++idCounter).toString();
```

As long as `Number.prototype.toString()` has not been overwritten, this will work.

Comment: ... or `String(++idCounter)`.

Comment: @raina77ow: Your way is nicer IMO.

Comment: Why? ) Afair, `Number.prototype.toString()` still will be called this way.

Comment: @raina77ow: Nicer, shorter syntax. Though I'd perfer the `+ ""`  overall.